# C# How to ensure an automatic double link between two objects

Tags: c#, oop, object, graph, linked-list

The target is to ensure a double link between objects, i.e. if I link object A to object B, then object B should be linked to object A automatically.

One of the potential uses of such system could be modelling an undirected graph.

I came up only with such a stupid implementation:

```
class ObjA
{
   public _addLink (object Obj)
   {
      <add code to store the single link to Obj>
   }
   public addLink (object Obj)
   {
      _addLink(Obj);
      Obj._addLink(this);
   }
} 

class ObjB
{
   public _addLink (object Obj)
   {
      <add code to store the single link to Obj>
   }
   public addLink (object Obj)
   {
      _addLink(Obj);
      Obj._addLink(this);
   }
}
```

Then I can write

```
ObjA.addLink(ObjB)
```

But the problem is that in this case I also can do

```
ObjA._addLink(ObjB)
```

And the system breaks, i.e. ObjB doesn't get a link to ObjA. And I cannot make _addLink private, as it won't be visible from another object.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: A reflexive link doesn't model a unidirectional graph so your requirements appear to be contradictory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note quiet sure what you are trying to do, but you can do the following with a base class, I.e duel linking, with private scope if needed

```
public class BaseLink 
{
   private BaseLink Link { get; set; }

   protected virtual void AddLink (BaseLink obj)
   {
      Link = obj;
      Link.AddLink(obj);

   }
}
public class ObjA : BaseLink
{

} 

public class ObjB : BaseLink
{
   public void Add(BaseLink baseLink)
   {
      AddLink(baseLink);
   }
} 

// or

public class ObjB : BaseLink
{
   public ObjB(BaseLink baseLink) => AddLink(baseLink); 
}
```